# Sobre implementação usando spring

Tags: java, mvc, spring, java-ee, spring-boot

Ola, Preciso de uma ajuda, tenho um banco com duas tabelas 1-Instituicao 2-Pessoas, pra isso criei na model essas 2 classes nao sei se é o jeito certo mais fiz assim.
Criei o Repository e extendi a classes Instituiçao(olhem na imagem) ate ai tudo bem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na Service criei o metodo para salvar, so que na Controller eu nao consigo chama o classe Pessoas pq so extendi a Instituiçao dai nao consigo salvar os dados do formulario de pessoas, nao sei se deu pra entender, nao tenho muito conhecimento provalvelmente to implementando de uma maneira errada, como eu poderia fazer ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saudações,

Vc precisa criar um Repository para `Pessoas` tbm:

```
@Repository
public interface PessoasRepository extends JpaRepository<Pessoas, Integer> {

}
```

Dessa forma vc irá utilizar esse repositório para salvar objetos Pessoas.
Vc pode até utilizar o mesmo service (Acredito que não seja o recomendado), mas crie métodos diferentes no seu service ou faça uma Sobrecarga do método que ficará da forma que vc quer, por exemplo:

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    EventoRepository eventoRepository; //recomendo trocar o nome desse repositório para InstituicaoRepository

    @Autowired
    PessoasRepository pessoasRepository;

    public void save(Instituicao instituicao) {
        eventoRepository.save(instituicao);
    }

    //UTILIZANDO A SOBRECARGA
    public void save(Pessoas pessoas) {
        pessoasRepository.save(pessoas);
    }

    //RESTANTE DO SEU CÓDIGO

}
```

Espero ter ajudado.